# ffmpeg batch converting audio files in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a lot of wav files (each with respective names) that need to be converted from wav to mp3 and I have been trying to write a batch file to do this.

I'm using the latest nightly build of ffmpeg on Windows 10 Insider build.

I've looked through the ffmpeg documentation but can't find anything on this.

I'm looking for a very simple and up-to-date ffmpeg script to accomplish this task.

Comment: You mentioned that you have a lot of mp3 files, but then you said you have to convert from wav to mp3. Are you converting wav to mp3, or mp3 to wav?

Comment: Show us your attempt, tell us what you expect it to do, with some examples, tell us what it actually did and then maybe we'll be able to suggest a better way or a fix.

Comment: @MassPikeMike I made a typo. I meant to say wav but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to process files one after the other, a simple `for` will do:

```
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
  echo processing %%a
  REM your ffmpeg command; Input file will be: %%a
  REM If you need some output file name: %%~na.mp3
)
```

see `for /?` for help.

Comment: for %%a in (*.wav) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%a" "%%~na.mp3"
)
PAUSE This worked and did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help, I needed some script to go off of.

Comment: for %a in (*.m4a) do ( ffmpeg -i "%a" "%~na.ogg" ) if you need to convert m4a files to ogg